# change the size of a UIView in a TableCell

Tags: objective-c, uiview, tablecell

I have a tableCell. In the cell i have a UIVIew with a background color.

I want to change the width of the UIView based on data.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i have put the following lines to change the width of the view.

```
//set the frame of the bar
CGRect  rect = cell.barView.frame;
rect.size.width = myViewWidth;
cell.barView.frame = rect;
```

There is no effect of this on setting the width of the UIVIew called `barView`.

The `barView` has the following constraints set in the cell.

1. Leading Space to SuperView = 0
2. Bottom Space to SuperView = 0
3. Height = 18
4. Width >=0

How do i get the barview to resize?

P.s. I have verified that myViewWidth is greater than 0 when the code executes in `cellForROwAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constraints to the width of your view and link to an IBOutlet inside the cell.

```
@interface historicoTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *lauguraFaixa;
```

[image]

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath change this constraint according to your need.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    historicoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[historicoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    int duracao = [self duracao:[[self.periodos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] inicio] data:[[self.periodos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] fim]];

    int diasMaximos = 9;
    int larguraMinima = 100;
    int larguraMaxima = 300;
    int largura = larguraMinima+((larguraMaxima-larguraMinima)/diasMaximos * duracao);

    cell.lauguraFaixa.constant = largura;


    return cell;
}
```